# li in unorder list moves

Tags: jquery, css

I have a ul list with hidden answers that get revealed with jQuery. However one li keeps moving out of position with I click a list item.

This oddity started when I made the red A. and when answer divs the same height by setting them all to float left and gave % with's.

I must have something wrong in the css to make the divs the same height. Not sure what though.

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/NkeHU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "clear:both;" to the style of the li tags.
See http://jsfiddle.net/spetnik/NkeHU/1/

Comment: Thanks very much, that did the trick. I have only ever used the clear on div's. Nice to learn something new